# Face unlock code in Android open source project?

Tags: android, opencv, face-recognition

Does anyone know the location of the face unlock code in the android source tree?  I'm looking to include some face recognition in my app and would love to use the code that google has already created.

I've already looked at the alternatives such as opencv and some other third party APIs,  but I'd really just like to see the way that google did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately:

> Face unlock is closed-source google proprietary code, so we have no opportunity to modify it.

Source: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1367610

Comment: Oh that sucks. I was hoping to rip this out and get it working on my desktop

Comment: does it have any API then? something we can fire and expect to get a result whether the person is the one we need ... ?