# HTC Face Unlock Training

Tags: android, android-intent, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

As described in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21645/how-do-i-train-face-unlock) on android.se regarding Face Unlock on HTC phones, it was discovered that HTC in all their wisdom have removed the ability to 'train' faces from their settings menu.

I was hoping to be able to write a one button app that would link to the missing feature (assuming it hasn't been removed entirely).

I assume that is an activity of some app, so presumably I could use an intent to open it.  However I have no idea how I would go about finding *which activity of which application to trigger*? I've looked through the developer reference and can't find anything, should I peer through the Android Source code?  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8632686/1091553) perhaps suggests that that wont help me though.

I could try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2780475/1091553) - would I use settings as the app to target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intent to invoke the training activity is called:

```
Package: com.android.facelock
Class: com.android.facelock.AddToSetup
```